# Active applying to only one element

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using jQuery to add active to my menu. It works on the index page, but I can't get it to work on the other pages right now. I've tried changing around the web address to fit the exact location.pathname but that doesn't seem to work, and I tried dropping the \ prior to it as well. Any help would be appreciated.

my markup:

```
<nav class="sticky-top navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-myColor">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="image/VC-Logo.png" alt="Visionary Creatives logo" height="150px;" />
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-brand" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navToggle" aria-controls="navToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navToggle">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/coming-soon.php">Web Design</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/coming-soon.php">Graphic Design</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/coming-soon.php">SEO &amp; Marketing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/coming-soon.php">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/coming-soon.php">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbar-nav .nav-item a[href="' + this.location.pathname + 
'"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

and my website if this helps as well:
http://www.visionary-creatives.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I go through your site's `view-source` page. I see that in remaining pages except for `index` page these scripts are missing at the end of the page source -

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
```

Please open your browser console and you will see some error over there. So, please add above scripts so that your code will run to every page

Your code is perfect and running as well.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was just a simple oversight on my part. Sometimes it's just hard to see the forest through the trees.

Comment: It's my pleasure. @ChrisHitchcock